# PHP WebSocket ZMQ - Chat Operation - Send data to specific user

Tags: php, symfony, websocket, zeromq, ratchet

im working on a PHP project based on Symfony 2.2.11 and I installed the socketo related to the following tutorial http://socketo.me/docs/install to make my chat script working.

**ServerCommand.php** // Code of the command line that starts the WebSocket server

```
$oLoop = Factory::create();

    // Listen for the web server to make a ZeroMQ push after an ajax request
    $oContext = new Context($oLoop);
    $oPull = $oContext->getSocket(\ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
    // LET IT 127.0.0.1
    $oPull->bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555'); // Binding to 127.0.0.1 means the only client that can connect is itself
    $oPull->on('message', array($oChat, 'onMessage'));

    // Set up our WebSocket server for clients wanting real-time updates
    $oWebSock = new Server($oLoop);
    $oWebSock->listen(7979, '0.0.0.0'); // Binding to 0.0.0.0 means remotes can connect
    $webServer = new IoServer(
        new HttpServer(
            new WsServer(
                new WampServer(
                    $oChat
                )
            )
        ),
        $oWebSock
    );

    $oLoop->run();
```

After a message is being added to database : 
**MessagesController.php**

```
....
// This is our new stuff
        $oContext = new \ZMQContext();
        $oSocket = $oContext->getSocket(\ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH, 'PushMe');
        $oSocket->connect("tcp://mydomain:5555");

        $aData = array(
            'topic'         => 'message',
            'sUsername'     => $oUserCurrent->getUsername(),
            'sMessage'      => $sMessage
        );

        $oSocket->send(json_encode($aData));
.....
```

The chat service : 
**Chat.php**

```
/**
 * A lookup of all the topics clients have subscribed to
 */
public function onSubscribe(ConnectionInterface $conn, $topic) 
{
    // When a visitor subscribes to a topic link the Topic object in a  lookup array
    $subject = $topic->getId();
    $ip = $conn->remoteAddress;

    if (!array_key_exists($subject, $this->subscribedTopics)) 
    {
        $this->subscribedTopics[$subject] = $topic;
    }

    $this->clients[] = $conn->resourceId;

    echo sprintf("New Connection: %s" . PHP_EOL, $conn->remoteAddress);

}

/**
 * @param string JSON'ified string we'll receive from ZeroMQ
 */
public function onMessage($jData) 
{
    $aData = json_decode($jData, true);

    var_dump($aData);

    if (!array_key_exists($aData['topic'], $this->subscribedTopics)) {
        return;
    }

    $topic = $this->subscribedTopics[$aData['topic']];

    // This sends out everything to multiple users, not what I want!!

    // re-send the data to all the clients subscribed to that category
    $topic->broadcast($aData);
}
```

JS code that receives data : 
**messages.html.twig** :

```
var conn = new ab.Session(
                    'ws://mydomain:7979' // The host (our Ratchet WebSocket server) to connect to
                  , function() {            // Once the connection has been established
                        conn.subscribe('message', function(topic, data) 
                        {
                            console.log(topic);
                            console.log(data);
                        });
                    }
                  , function() {            // When the connection is closed
                        console.warn('WebSocket connection closed');
                    }
                  , {                       // Additional parameters, we're ignoring the WAMP sub-protocol for older browsers
                        'skipSubprotocolCheck': true
                    }
                );
```

So everytings working perfectly, when I send a new Message, it goes to DB then it lands on the page of the chat.

**PROBLEM :** 
The data lands wherever the JS script is, and the result is that all users can get the same recorded message

**ASKING :**
How can I make data lands in a **specific user** page ?

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583903/how-to-get-the-connection-object-of-a-specific-user#17737332

Comment: Yes I did, we are not working by the same method, his Chat class extends MessageComponentInterface refering to http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world and my Chat class extends WampServerInterface refering to http://socketo.me/docs/push

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `Ratchet` on backend side, right?

So, here you have very good example of case you need:

http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world

You should keep your client connections inside `$clients` property (not collection of resources id!). So, you can choose one element from this collection and send a message only to this client.

Example:

```
public function onSubscribe(ConnectionInterface $conn, $topic) 
{
    // When a visitor subscribes to a topic link the Topic object in a  lookup array
    $subject = $topic->getId();
    $ip = $conn->remoteAddress;

    if (!array_key_exists($subject, $this->subscribedTopics)) 
    {
        $this->subscribedTopics[$subject] = $topic;
    }

    $this->clients[] = $conn; // you add connection to the collection

    $conn->send("Hello new user!"); // you send a message only to this one user
}
```

Comment: Just tryed it and it doesnt work, still broadcasting it to all browser pages which are openning the receiving page. I want to send the message to a specific Username account (Symfony) for example if thats possible

Comment: Could you please contribute on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29576033/send-a-value-from-browser-to-websocket-server-while-opening-connection, you for sure can help, thanks very much in advance