# Send user ID from browser to websocket server while opening connection

Tags: websocket, real-time, zeromq, ratchet

> Before asking this question, I did my best by reading severel
>   questions on SO (tagged Ratchet and dealing with similar issues but to
>   no avail. I even asked a question which received no attention and I
>   therefore deleted it to write another one (that hopefully is more
>   clear).

My final goal is to build a one-to-one private chat application using Ratchet. Everything is working fine except that I can't send message to a specific user.

Every logged in user connects to the websocket server while accessing secured area of website:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
        conn.onopen = function(e) {
            console.log("Connection established!");

            // Here I need to send the logged in user_id to websocket server
            // and get it in onOpen method so that I can index my array 
            // of connections with user_id instead of
            //$connection->ResourceId, I explain more below

        };

        conn.onmessage = function(e) {
            console.log(e.data);
        };

});
```

When a user writes a message in the chat box, the message is sent via AJAX to web server then pushed to Websocket using ZeroMQ. In the controller:

```
// Persistence of Message(message_id, sender_id, receiver_id, message_text)
                .....

                $context = new \ZMQContext();
                $socket = $context->getSocket(\ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH, 'my pusher');
                $socket->connect("tcp://localhost:5555");

                $pushData = array(
                       'receiver_id' => $receiver_id,
                       'sender_id'  => $user->getId(),
                       'message'  => $message->getMessageText(),
                    );
                $socket->send(json_encode($pushData));
```

So at the end, my websocket server is able to know which is the id of receiver using the JSON. But how will he know which is the connection of that user? In other words, I need to store websocket connections in an array that is indexed by the user id.

```
<?php
namespace RealTime;

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use Ratchet\Wamp\WampServerInterface;

class Pusher implements WampServerInterface, MessageComponentInterface{

    private $clients;

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {

        $this->clients[$conn->resourceId] = $conn;
        // I need here to get the user_id received from browser while opening connection
    }

    public function onMessageEntry($entry) {
        $entryData = json_decode($entry, true);

        //This is not what I need (It sends to all users in array)
        foreach ($this->clients as $key => $client) {

        $client->send($entryData['message']); 
        }
    }
    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        echo $msg; 
    }
}
```

And the websocket server:

```
  <?php
        require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
        use RealTime\Pusher;

        $loop   = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
        $pusher = new Pusher;

        $context = new React\ZMQ\Context($loop);
        $pull = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
        $pull->bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555'); 
        $pull->on('message', array($pusher, 'onMessageEntry'));


        $webSock = new React\Socket\Server($loop);
        $webSock->listen(8080, '0.0.0.0'); 
        $webServer = new Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
            new Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
                new Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
                    new Ratchet\Wamp\WampServer(
                        $pusher
                    )
                )
            ),
            $webSock
        );
        $loop->run();

        ?>
```

**Questions:**

1. How to send the logged in `user_id` from client side while opening connection.I need to have the value in websocket server so that I can index my array of clients with it (`$client[user_id]=$conn` instead of `$client[recourceId]=$conn`). I tried the javascript function `send` but I don't know where to receive the sent data (even `onMessage` is not printing anything).
2. Why the `onMessage` method is not executing even `MessageComponentInterface` implemented (Is it because I have `onMessageEntry` method + `$pull->on('message', array($pusher, 'onMessageEntry'));` line of code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I found and any suggestions to enhance this solution are welcome.

One can use the Ratchet [SessionProvider](http://socketo.me/docs/sessions). This will require using one of the Symfony Custom Session handlers as indicated. I use in the following code the  `PdoSessionHandler`.

```
<?php
    require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    use YourDirectory\Pusher;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler;

    use \Ratchet\Session\SessionProvider;

    $pusher = new Pusher;

    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=community', 'root', null);

    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    //This info is related to you db
    $dbOptions = array(
        'db_table'      => 'session',
        'db_id_col'     => 'sess_id',
        'db_data_col'   => 'sess_data',
        'db_time_col'   => 'sess_time',);

        $loop   = \React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
        $context = new \React\ZMQ\Context($loop);
        $pull = $context->getSocket(\ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
        $pull->bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555');
        $pull->on('message', array($pusher, 'onMessageEntry'));

        $webSock = new React\Socket\Server($loop);
        $webSock->listen(8080, '0.0.0.0'); // Binding to 0.0.0.0 means remotes can connect
        $webServer = new Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
            new Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
                new Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
                    new SessionProvider(
                        new Ratchet\Wamp\WampServer(
                            $pusher
                        ),new Handler\PdoSessionHandler($pdo,$dbOptions)
                    )
                )
            ),
            $webSock
        );

        $loop->run();
    ?>
```

Then my stub class will become:

```
   public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {  
        $this->clients[$conn->Session->get('current_user_id')] = $conn;
    }

public function onMessageEntry($entry) {

            $entryData = json_decode($entry, true);
            $ReceiverConnection=$this->clients[$entryData['receiver_id']];
            $ReceiverConnection->send($entryData['message']);                  
        }
```

But before, I have added  the user id to the session in Web server (in the controller that returns the initial page)

```
$user = $this->getUser();
$request->getSession()->set('current_user_id', $user->getId());
```

PS:

1. Moving to PdoSessionHandler can be done by implementing [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/pdo_session_storage.html) (Symfony).
2. I still can't answer 2 but all the logic that can be put `onMessage` is now moved to `onMessageEntry` which satisfies temporarly the needs.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative way to make the association between your `clientConnection` and his `ID` you need to send a message using websockets just after opening the connection to your websocket server this message will contain your user id you will use it to index his connection object by his `ID` in your array.

For the second question as I know the default websocket implementation is not working properly specialy with `pubsub` protocol you need to use a websocket  library for that I suggest to use [`AutobahnJS`](http://autobahn.ws/js/) it's a good websocket library with a lot of wonderfull features.

Comment: Thank you Anas for your usual contribution. your alternative was the first thing i tried. I did with javascript while openening connection using `send` function, but I don't find a way to get the value in the Pusher class. Your solution is what I really look for and SessionProvider were used because I just failed. Where to get the sent id in websocket server?\

Comment: You didn't receive data because the default implementation of websockets in web browsers is not working properly with pubsub protocole try to use it with AuthobahnJS it have an implementation of pubsub protocole.

Comment: look at this, I didn't use PDOSessionProvider because the session don't have the same lifecycle as your connection object take a look at this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ratchet-php/LNCsDIugvBg

Comment: okey I see what you mean. I will try with AuthobanhnJS and give a feedback. thanks for google groups link

Answer (score 3):

Actually on my last try, I gave up on PHP WebSocket (it was so complicated to make this work) and started using SocketIO with nodeJS that solved my entire problem and could give me a functionnal simple Chat system.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience with the whole community.